# How to verify if a single object is present with a CNN

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm doing a school project on traffic sign recognition. I'm using the colors of signs to crop them  [image: Cropped sign], but the problem is that there are other objects in the environment that are red [image: Cropped image of a red car given by my other algorithm]. Because of that I'm trying to create an Ai that would try to tell if it's the picture of a sign or not.

So the problem is that I don't really understand how to train such an AI, i've tried to create an AI with a single node as an output with a sigmoid activator but then I don't really know how to do the validation, at least I don't know how to labelize the picture which are not signs since the training input only has one class of images(the signs).

```
for images in os.listdir(pathb):
    img=Image.open(path+'\\Test\\0\\'+str(images))
    img=img.resize((30,30))
    img=np.array(img)
    data.append(img)
    labels.append(0)

model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=X_train.shape[1:])
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(9,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```